# Swift (Xcode 7.3.1) and sorting using values in a Dictionary

Tags: swift, sorting, nsmutabledictionary

I have an array of dictionaries that appears as below and I want to sort and store it such that the objects are sorted based on the 'value' of the 'Like' key ? How do I do this in Swift ? Thanks.

```
{
    Dislike = 0;
    Like = 5;
    userName = T; }
{
    Dislike = 0;
    Like = 0;
    userName = S; }
{
    Dislike = 0;
    Like = 10;
    userName = N; }
```

Comment: I don't really understand what this data structure you showed is. It sounds like an array of dictionaries. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, its an array of Dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that's an array of dictionaries?

If it is the case, you can sort them as follows

```
//AnyObject in case your number is an NSNumber
var array: [[String:AnyObject?]] = yourArray 

array.sort{ $0["Like"]!! > $1["Like"]!! }
```

basically it mutates the array and sort based on the "Like" key.

Comment: Two things: (1) `AnyObject` cannot be compared by `>`. (2) `sort` does not mutate the array, `sortInPlace` does.

Comment: 1)That's why I do a double unwrapping. 2) I'm sorry you're right. I've been working lately with Swift 3 and I forgot. In Swift 3 it does mutate the array.

Answer (score 0):

This data structure looks really weird you know. I think it is a `[[String: Any]]`. It should be declared like this:

```
let data: [[String: Any]] = [
    [
        "Dislike": 0,
        "Like": 5,
        "username": "T"],

    [
        "Dislike": 0,
        "Like": 0,
        "username": "S"],

    [
        "Dislike": 0,
        "Like": 10,
        "username": "N"],
]
```

To sort it, simply use the `sort` function. In the closure, you should return whether the first parameter should be ordered before the second parameter. In this case, you would like to only compare the values corresponding to the key `"Like"`. The closure body would look something like this: (pseudocode)

```
firstParameter["Like"] < secondParameter["Like"]
```

as I said, that is pseudocode. The real code is a little more complicated:

```
data.sort { ($0["Like"]! as! Int) < ($1["Like"] as! Int) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sweeper and Edder are right, it looks like an array of structs. You can also omit the semicolon.

```
struct s {
    var Dislike: Int = 0
    var Like: Int = 0
    var userName: String = ""
}

var myArray = [s]()
var i = s()

i.Dislike = 0
i.Like = 5
i.userName = "T"
myArray.append(i)

i.Dislike = 0
i.Like = 0
i.userName = "S"
myArray.append(i)

i.Dislike = 0
i.Like = 10
i.userName = "N"
myArray.append(i)

myArray.sort{$0.Like < $1.Like}
```